# Clear certain columns from Target cell selected

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to clear certain columns from selected cell.

User can select some cell. Let's say cell from row 10. Currently cells in column B, C, E, F are unlocked, so B10 or E10 or F10 or C10 in this case. There are should be no matter in which column cell is selected B, C, E, F. In this example code should clear values in cells B10, E10, F10 and C10.

How this is possible to achieve?

My current solution clears all the cells in certain row. I have formulas in Column D and current code removes them.

```
Sub TimescheduleDelete()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = ActiveCell

    If Intersect(ActiveCell, Timeschedule.Range("B8:B90")) Is Nothing Then

    Else

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Target.EntireRow.ClearContents
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.SpecialCells` and `xlCellTypeConstants` will skip over cells containing formulas

```
Sub TimescheduleDelete()   
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Timeschedule.Range("B8:B90")) Is Nothing Then  
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1-ActiveCell.Column).ClearContents
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True    
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This is actually an answer to my question. I have just tested and noticed that this would work fine for my, but I have formula in column A that I want to remove and leave formula in Column D. Should I ask new question or you can give me a hint in your current answer how to perform such a task?

Comment: Thank you! What a clever solution with `1-ActiveCell.Column`